# Unknown constructor

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension

I have a page that creates a CSV of account and related data, i am trying to add a block that shows the users related to that account via a contact.

I have followed a few tutorials on how to make a custom list controller class however every iteration i have tried gives me a unknown constructor error.

Where is the issue?

Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls" cache="true"  extensions="AccountRegisteredPortalUsers">

    <apex:pageBlock title="Agency Planning" rendered="{!$user.id = account.CSM_owner__r.id}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Cases}" var="item"> 
            <apex:column value="{!item.Subject}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!item.Status}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>    

    <apex:pageBlock title="Entitlements" rendered="{!$user.id = account.CSM_owner__r.id}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Entitlements}" var="Ent"> 
            <apex:column value="{!Ent.PlanType__C}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>    

    <apex:pageBlock title="RegisteredUsers" rendered="{!$user.id = account.CSM_owner__r.id}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Usercont}" var="Ent"> 
            <apex:column value="{!Usercont.userid}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>   

</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class AccountRegisteredPortalUsers {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController Usercont {
        get{
        if(Usercont == null) {
            Usercont = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
            [SELECT 
             id,
             Contactid
            FROM user Where contact.accountid = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')]));
    }
    return Usercont;
    }
    set;
    }
    public AccountRegisteredPortalUsers(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    }

//Initalize orderSetCont and return a list of records
    public List<User> getuserDets() {
        return (List<User>) Usercont.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `recordSetVar="accounts"` attribute on your `<apex:page>` tag. Otherwise, the Visualforce system believes you to be using an `ApexPages.StandardController` rather than an `ApexPages.StandardSetController`.

As a result, you get a constructor-related error because Visualforce is looking for

```
public AccountRegisteredPortalUsers(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
```

and you have

```
public AccountRegisteredPortalUsers(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, however now the standard records for <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Entitlements}" var="Ent">  and cases dont show any values, i did think perhaps it was because it didn't recognise the 'rendered' account check but removing that doesn't help. Is there something i should look at to allow the standard and Ext records to display side by side? Thanks

Comment: You don't appear to have an `account` property accessible anywhere. Is this code complete?

Comment: It is, im sure there is something im missing. Originally i returned the two child lists using value="{!Account.Cases}". Has adding the extension and 'StandardSetController' Removed the relationship for these fields? If so what is the best way of getting access to those sObjects/Fields again?

Comment: A standard set controller controls a collection of objects, in this case Accounts. It doesn't have a property for a single Account. You'd need to iterate over its contents using a component like `<apex:repeat>`. I don't have enough clarity on what you're trying to do to make a more concrete recommendation, but if you aren't working with a set of objects, a set controller is probably not what you want.

Comment: Ok thanks, looks like i need to go do some research. I was attempting to return three page blocks, the first two would be child objects of the account from the current page (the page is called in a button) the third is users that are related to that account via the user.contactid.accountid relationship as there is no way to access those user records directly from the account

Comment: That does not sound like a use case for a set controller - you probably just want the standard controller.

Comment: thanks, and is an extension the correct way to go to get the user records?

Comment: It is indeed. You could write a full custom controller, but an extension should be plenty to get what you need.